# plot correlation between several bam files

Tags: sam, sequence-alignment, sequence-analysis, chip-seq, deeptools

I have several mab files from medip-seq. they supposed to be replicates and I have to draw their correlation. First I used multiBamSummary from deeptools to merge all the bam files based on bi/bed. Now when I am using the plotCorrelation I do not get any file. the argument is :

```
plotCorrelation --corData myMultiBamSumary.npz --corMethod spearman --whatToPlot scatterplot --skipZeros --removeOutliers --plotFile Myplot --plotFileFormat pdf
```

Is that the correct strategy to pot the correlation? Is there any suggestion?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

That's a completely normal way to plot correlation between them. Spearman correlation was a wise choice on your part, since it's rank based and you don't have to care as much about normalization.

Update: It turns out that matplotlib is broken and I need to have a new deepTools release to work around that. That should be available sometime Sunday.

Comment: here is the file.  Thanks much   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wKuHg3IfJWBCUwrInk4UZIA7mO80Pl7U

Comment: I suspect this is a matplotlib bug, I'll investigate.

Comment: There's a matplotlib bug that I need to program around. The fix is very simple and I'll release a new deepTools versions as soon as possible (sometime Sunday).

Comment: Thanks alot looking forward to it

Comment: 3.4.2 is now on pypi and will be available via conda sometime today.

Comment: Much appreciate.